# Duplicate Content from "simple accordian css3 & jQuery"

Tags: jquery, html, redirect, duplicates

I have a website that may have duplicate content for an unusual reason. The site uses a piece of code called "Simple Accordian CSS3 & jQuery". You can find that code here: `htmldrive.net/items/show/543/Simple-Accordion-CSS3-and-jQuery`

This accordian uses an ID that alters the URL structure when it is expanded. So, if the ID is called "benefits" in the accordian, the URL will change from `www.example.com/page.html` to `www.example.com/page.html?section=benefits` when the accordian is expanded.

I use siteliner.com to check for internal duplicate content and siteliner recognizes both the original version of the URL and the modified version (with `?section=ID` appended to the URL) and tells me that I have 100% duplicate content across both pages. The website ranks really poorly and I think this is why.

Is Google seeing the same duplicate content as siteliner and automatically penalizing me?

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Likely SiteLiner is not running the javascript on the page and just looking at the raw response(s).